# Selenium webdriver integration with Jenkins

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

How can I integrate selenium webdriver c# - MSunit tests to run on the Jenkins server as part of CI/CD

Answer (score 1):

you need to use step `Windows Batch Script` and write there the exact command which is executing your tests locally (not from IDE but from local command promot or powershell)

after that if you need to publish test results consume plugin for MSunit and give the path of generated test rauls file to it.